# jquery ajax with two service calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a better to write the following?

I have two services that I need to call.

The data returned from the first service is needed to create the url for the second ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://service',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 1000,
        error: function(){
            alert('Error loading json document');
        },
        success: function(json){
            processJson(json.foo);
        }
    });


    function processJson(url) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 1000,
        error: function(){
            alert('Error loading json document');
        },
        success: function(json){
                displayJson(json.foo);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nope, thats how I would do it. Maybe I'd use some of the built inn ajax functions, or create a function with those parameters preset:

```
function ajax(url, error, success){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(){
      alert('Error loading json document');
    },
    success: success,
  });
}


ajax('http://service', function(json){
  ajax(json.foo, function(json){
    displayJson(json.foo);
  });
});
```